# 2005 volvo s60 2.4 starts shuts right off.

Tags: starting, volvo

I put a new fuel pressure sensor in 4 days ago ran fine. Now it is coding fuel pressure sensor low pressure but I do not hear the fuel pump buzz at startup is it the fuel pump?

Comment: If you're reading the code from your own scanner see if it can also read a Fuel Pressure PID and have that as a reference for when you measure your actual pressure with a [Fuel Gauge](https://www.fcpeuro.com/products/volvo-fuel-system-pressure-gauge-kit-s60-v70-xc70-s80-xc90-cta-cta-3448)

Answer (score 2):

It might be the fuel pump. Something you can replace before your fuel pump is the fuel filter. If this becomes clogged, it can give a lower pressure at the fuel rails and could trigger a low fuel pressure code to your ECM. If this doesn't work for you, then I'd check the fuel pump. The easiest way to tell is to put a fuel pressure tester at the fuel rail to see what it comes up to when you turn the key on. Most current vehicles with fuel injection has a test port which is a Schraeder valve (same basic thing as what holds air in your tires) on it (not to be confused with either of the A/C ports). I don't know exactly what the fuel pressure should be on your vehicle, but believe it should be around 43psi.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the fuel pressure sensor, and you have a low fuel pressure reading. The fuel pressure sensor reports the fuel pressure in the system. This pressure is controlled by the **fuel pressure regulator**. You will need to have a fuel pressue test which at idle should be 3.7-3.9 bar. A low reading will point at the fuel pressure regulator on the fuel rail.

Comment: I don't believe these Volvos use a regulator, I'd guess that pressure is maintained electronically by their [Fuel Pump Control Module](https://www.fcpeuro.com/products/volvo-fuel-pump-control-module-30742823). It's true that as you work your way from the rail to the pump you could stumble across a bad regulator that could be interfering with the flow.